# Merge process gives priority to library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard, android-vectordrawable

I have a really strange problem with my project, and I am trying to solve it for past 2 days. I have Android project that has `:app` and `:lib` module. Both `:app` and `:lib` have same `drawable/ic_add.xml`. Problem is that for some reason app always uses drawable from `:lib`. If I rename drawable in `:lib`, everything is fine, and the app starts using drawable from the `:app`.

Does anyone have an idea why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

It's happening only with vector drawables. All other resources are from `:app`.

Answer (score 0):

I have face this issue and I have solved that by renaming of drawable name. 
In activity you can manage that thing with R.drawable.ic_add.xml, where R is class of :app.

Comment: Renaming is an option that I am aware of. Problem is that it's happening for all other resources, like strings. And there is a lot of them. But anyway, I don't know why is this happening :(. Resources from lib should be rewritten by resources from the app.